# Gluster Arbiter-3 StorageClass volumetype in kubernetes-gluster?

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

What `volumetype` would I use in my **kubernetes-gluster** `StorageClass` for **arbiter-3** volumes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `parameters` section of the [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#glusterfs) you can

```
volumeoptions: user.heketi.arbiter true
```

Any PVCs provisioned through that StorageClass will have one arbiter and two data bricks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure Gluster volumes manually, there is no difference for Kubernetes what to mount - the regular GlusterFS volume or the GlusterFS Arbiter-3 volume. So, Volume Type should be `glusterfs` and you need to provide only the Volume name. Here is the example, more information is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/glusterfs):

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "glusterfsvol",
    "glusterfs": {
      "endpoints": "glusterfs-cluster",
      "path": "kube_vol",
      "readOnly": true
    }
  }
]
```

If you want Kubernetes to provision Gluster volumes automatically, you need to dig deeper. Use [these instructions](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes) from GitHub.